# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using the same NSFileHandle object in a Cordova plugin

Tags: objective-c, cordova, nsfilehandle

I'm experiencing an access problem in my Cordova plugin: my `NSFileHandle` "loses" context between Cordova calls, and I end up with either an **EXC_BAD_ACCESS**, a **SIGABRT** or an **Unrecognized Selector sent to instance** error. Debugging and digging inside Obj-C's documentation has given me no lead on this, so I'd appreciate your help here very much!

Here's my code. First - the interface:

```
@interface MyPlugin : CDVPlugin
...
- (void) startWriting:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;
- (void) stopWriting:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;
@end
```

And the implementation:

```
....
static NSFileHandle *logFile;


@implementation MyPlugin

- (void) startWriting:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command{
    logFile = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:@"path_to_my_file"];
    NSData nsData = [@"Hello World!" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [logFile writeData:nsData];
}

- (void) stopWriting:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command{
    NSData nsData = [@"Goodbye World!" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   [logFile writeData:nsData];   
}
```

I call `startWriting` and then `stopWriting` using `cordova.exec`. The error occurs on the last line of `stopWriting`. There were a few times that the problem miraculously disappeared, but in most cases I get one of the aforementioned errors.
It appears that my `logFile` object closes the file seamlessly, but according to iOS documentation, this usually happens when the `NSFileHandle` object is deallocated, whereas my object is declared as **static**, and is not supposed to be deallocated as long as my plugin lives (plus, I see in the XCode debugger that it is still allocated).

What, in your opinion, causes my `NSFileHandle` object to "lose" the actual file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683624/exc-bad-access-sigabrt-ios-crash-log.

Comment: Do you mean to say that the source for my problem is unknown? Because I debugged the code and kept failing on the same `[logFile writeData:nsData]` line over and over again. I'm sure that this is the problematic line, because `stopWriting` is called as the result of a button pressed by me.

Comment: i don't know what is real problem but i just want to help you :) thanks :)

Comment: Thank you! So do you think I can gain from using the DebugConsole offered in the link you pasted, if I already know which line is failing and that the `logFile` object is not **nil** in that line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imho - logFile is released once function finishes its job. You should change your code to something like

```
if (logFile==nil) logFile = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:@"path_to_my_file"];
```

or manually retain/release the logFile object.

Comment: Well, using this code snippet (according to your second suggestion) helped me solve the problem: `if (logFile==nil) logFile = [[NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:@"path_to_my_file"]retain];`. Thanks!!!
Does this mean that **static** variables don't last as long as the encapsulating object lasts? I mean - doesn't the line `static NSFileHandle *logFile;` mean that `logFile` has a reference even after the method ends?

Comment: Maybe you want to make it "strong" instead of "static"? ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013587/differences-between-strong-and-weak-in-objective-c )

Comment: Thanks! But I want to have an ivar, not a property, and as far as I understand only properties may be defined as strong.